# Can somebody please explain Canonical's ubuntu security webpage?

Tags: security, lts, software-sources, source

take this url for example: 
[CVE-2017-100112](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-1000112.html)

I can see there are many "Packages" listed as small tables, I have multiple questions regarding them, take this package for example
[image]
1. Why are there so many packages each for different os releases? e.g. why are there linux-lts-trusty package for Ubuntu 12.04 ESM (Precise Pangolin)? Won't  there only linux-lts-trusty for Ubuntu 14.04 be enough?

2.What's the difference between `linux-lts-*` package and `linux` package? (I'm not asking what is lts, just the difference between packages in the list I provided).

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134269/how-to-read-cve-2016-5696-correctly

Comment: Actually I was reading that, but that post did not address my problem such as: why do they need to compile linux-lts-xenial for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Hardware enablement is the basic answer, new hardware comes out all the time, so LTS releses need to upgrade the kernel to support new hardware after release. I am no experty on this, so I will point you here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack for some reading. LTS is long term support, 5 years of support. non-lts only gets 6 months of support.

Comment: @Sajuuk as far as I know all packages are matched with all current versions and the ones that are not present in that system get a DNE (does not exist). And yes, the HWE are a part of these as Mark pointed out.